# I wrote this code but it says the constructor Double (String) is deprecated since version 9

Tags: java, deprecated

I wrote this code but it says the constructor Double (String) is deprecated since version 9, can someone just tell me with what can I replace it, or just copy paste the code and just post it, here is the code:

```
public class Quadratic {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double a = new Double(args[0]).doubleValue();
    double b = new Double (args[1]).doubleValue();
    double c = new Double (args[2]).doubleValue();
    
    double x1 =(-b + Math.sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a);
    double x2 =(-b + Math.sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a);
    System.out.println("x =" + x1 + "ose x= " + x2);
    

}
```

}

And here is the error image:
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2AiD.png)

Comment: `Double.parseDouble(String)`

Comment: Why don't you look at the documentation?

Comment: Post text here rather than images, whenever practical.

Answer (score 6):

Just look at [your documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#Double-java.lang.String-)!

> Deprecated. It is rarely appropriate to use this constructor. **Use `parseDouble(String)` to convert a string to a `double` primitive, or use `valueOf(String)` to convert a string to a `Double` object.**

Answer (score 1):

From the Java 9 documentation for Double constructor:

> It is rarely appropriate to use this constructor. Use
> parseDouble(String) to convert a string to a double primitive, or use
> valueOf(String) to convert a string to a Double object.

So, use [Double.parseDouble(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble-java.lang.String-) instead of the constructor.

Something like:

```
public class Quadratic {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length >= 3) {
        double a = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
        double b = Double.parseDouble(args[1]);
        double c = Double.parseDouble(args[2]);
        
        double x1 =(-b + Math.sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a);
        double x2 =(-b + Math.sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a);
        System.out.println("x =" + x1 + "ose x= " + x2);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Need to specify 3 doubles!");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How, can you just show the solution copy pasted to my code that I posted please

Comment: How to specify 3 double I don't get it, Im e begineer at programming please help??

Comment: Your code is assuming 3 doubles.  You are trying to parse three command line arguments.  That's why I added the check to make sure there are at least 3.  It's up to you how you want to do this though.

Comment: How to add more than 3 doubles

Comment: That's getting outside of the scope of your original question.  You might want to read up on Oracle's [Command Line Args](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html) documentation as well as [reading values from the command line](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/cl.html) via Console.